# SSH Config setup to assign multiple SSH keys for two Repositories

Tags: github

Our project currently has set up two repositories in Github.   We are looking to use the GitHub "Deploy Key" feature to set up a different SSH key for each repo.

I realized after googling that I need to use .ssh/config file to direct which ssh key file is to be used for each repo.

Would like some assistance with setting up the .ssh/config  - I have provided the remote.origin.url value along with the SSH key file to be used for each repo:

repo # 1:

remote.origin.url=git@wwwin-github.XYZ.com:Services/repo1.git

ssh key:  .ssh/id_rsa.pub

repo # 2:

remote.origin.url=git@wwwin-github.XYZ.com:Services/repo2.git

ssh key:  .ssh/id_rsa2.pub

P.S.  Am setting this up on WINDOWS platform.